# react native - Overlay above certain components only

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display a simple overlay, but over certain components only.

Example code:

```
<Animated.View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text style={ [{zIndex: 0}, styles.titleText] }>Title under overlay</Text>
    <Animated.View style={ [styles.overlay] } />
    <View style={{ zIndex: 2, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ zIndex: 2, fontSize: 32, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center' }}>Subtitle above overlay</Text>
        <Text style={ [{ zIndex: 0 }, styles.descriptionText] }>Text under overlay</Text>
        <Text style={ [{ zIndex: 0 }, styles.descriptionText] }>Text above overlay</Text>
    </View>
</Animated.View>
```

As mentioned, I need some of the components above the Overlay and others under it.

Right now, all components written in code after the overlay view, comes above overlay. I want specifically the component saying "Text under overlay" to come under overlay but the other text should be above.

How do I go about it? zIndex is not working the way I want it to.

Comment: Have you tried setting a zIndex on your overlay as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the overlay the by the combination of `position: 'absolute'` and `zIndex` in the following way.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent', top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0, zIndex: 0}} /> //... Here is the overlay
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', position: 'absolute', top: 0,  bottom:  200, right: 0, left: 0, zIndex: 1}} >
                // Set the elements over the overlay here
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue',  position: 'absolute', top: 0,  bottom:  100, right: 0, left: 0, zIndex: -1}} >
                // Set the elements under the overlay here
      </View>
</View>
```

Here's the sample snack [**demo**](https://snack.expo.io/SkKBPda6f)